# Django storing lazy translation

Tags: django, translation

While trying to implement a translated version of a website, I came across the following problem:

Let say I have a model defined like that:

```
class Model(models.model)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    ...
```

To create some data (which are later displayed on a web page), I use a special view that includes lines like:

```
Model.objects.create(name = "testName",...)
```

I tried to implement the translation with the following code:

```
Model.objects.create(name = _("testName"),...)
```

If I import `ugettext` as `_` , it just put the translated value of "testName" in the database.
If I import `ugettext_lazy` as `_`, I have an `InterfaceError` (more precisely `Error binding parameter X - probably unsupported type`.

I was wondering if such an initialization is possible of if I have to find some workarounds.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just store the english version in the db and only call ugettext/_lazy during output. This obviously only works as long as translations for those strings exist, otherwise it will display the english version either way…

Comment: Agreed, call it during output. Perhaps a useful addition: the root cause is that it is a database restriction. The database only contains regular strings, not python objects that python can later translate automatically.

Comment: I started this way when i first tried. Seeing that there seems to be no other easy options, i'll end up doing that anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`ugettext` and `ugettext_lazy` are used for static I18N translations. They are applied on translatable text in code to collect the text to `.po` files and finally in `.mo` files.
Normally for dynamic text, you need to create translation schema in DB through Django ORM and to edit translations in views such as Django Admin. Then in your view, show correct version of translations according to the requested language.
You could 'store' a `ugettext_lazy` `__proxy__` to DB by pickling it, and could unpickle and apply `unicode` on it to get the translation. However, IMO, its meaningless to store a literal from code to DB.

If you want po-based translation solution which is managed through Web interface, ref https://github.com/mbi/django-rosetta

Comment: Thanx for the heads up, your solutions seems a bit overkill for my project tho (it's a tiny project, i was just exploring django possibility)

Answer (score 0):

Just adding that in case someone need it.

It's the best way I found to implement Florian solution and to avoid the need to add/remove the `_` function each time. 
You'll define a dummy function in the file containing the strings:

```
def _(input):
     return input
```

This way, your strings are going to be stored in the original language, but `makemessages` is still going to process them like a string that needs translation, thus putting them in the `.po` files. And you'll just have to use `{% trans %}` block in html.